# Get the product of non-zero element of sparse banded matrix and vector in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a large banded sparse matrix S with few non-zero elements in its rows and columns. And I have vector b, I want to calculate sum(S*tcrossprod(b)). But because the data is too large, the system can't calculate it, I need to multiply the non-zero parts in S, how can I do that? Thanks!
Here is the example data:

```
S = matrix(rnorm(64),8,8)
bw = 3
pick = (row(S)<(col(S) - bw)) | (row(S)>(col(S)+bw))
S[pick] = 0
S.r <- sample(1:8,40,replace = T)
S.c <- sample(1:8,40,replace = T)
for (i in 1:length(S.r)) {
  S[S.r[i],S.c[i]] <-0
}
S <- as(S,"sparseMatrix")
rowlab = collab = NULL
for (ii in 1:S@Dim[2]) {
     n <- S@i[(S@p[ii]+1):S@p[ii+1]]
     rowlab <-c(rowlab, n)
     collab <- c(collab, rep(ii,length(n)))
     lab.b <- data.frame(rowlab = rowlab+1, collab = collab)
 }
b = rnorm(8)
```

And I want to get

```
sum(S*tcrossprod(b))
```

For the real data, the dimension of S is c(20000,20000), and the dimension of b is c(20000,1).

Comment: If the matrix is huge, then you can loop through each element and sum up every parts. You don't need to save the cross product matrix before sum. Instead, simply summing the element products and accumulated in one variable.

Comment: What is the error that you get when you run `sum(S * tcrossprod(b))`? Have you tried `sum((S * tcrossprod(b))@x)`?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the dimensions of `S` and `b` in your real case please. If `b` is very large then `tcrossprod(b)` will take up a bunch of memory -- is this where your PC struggles?

Comment: is `(S * b) %*% Diagonal(x=b)` any better?

Comment: @MikaelJagan, The error is "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.1 Gb", and I tried sum((S * tcrossprod(b))@x), it showed the same error.

Comment: @user20650, thanks, I added the dimensions. Since b is too big, I get an error even if I run it on the server. And could you please explain this (S * b) %*% Diagonal(x=b)? I don't know how to implement x=b

Comment: That could uses functions from the `Matrix` package, which I assume that you are using. The `x=b` in `Diagonal(x=b)` just creates a sparse diagonal matrix with the values of `b` on the diagonal. But I think this will be even faster: `dp = diff(S@p); j = rep(seq_along(dp),dp); S@x = S@x * b[S@i+1]*b[j]; S`

Comment: @Sixiang.Hu, thanks, I think the problem is that too large b to get tcrossprod(b).  Actually, I have the similar idea to you and write some code for this, but it doesn't work for my real data. Could you provide some example code?

Comment: @user20650 Can you post that as an answer? That is almost certainly "optimal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into memory issues due to the dense matrix returned from `tcrossprod(b)`. But as many of the terms of this are getting multiplied by zero we can avoid calculating some of the values  (avoid generating the full cross-product). You can grab the indices of the non-zero elements of the sparse matrix `S`, use these to index the vector `b` and multiply. Below are a couple of ways to calculate `S * tcrossprod(b)`:

```
library(Matrix)

# Several functions to calculate the matrix products:
f1 <- function(S, b) S*tcrossprod(b)
f2 <- function(S, b) (S * b) %*% Diagonal(x=b) 
f3 <- function(S, b) {indices = summary(S); S@x = S@x * b[indices$i]*b[indices$j]; S}
f4 <- function(S, b) {dp = diff(S@p); j = rep(seq_along(dp),dp); S@x = S@x * b[S@i+1]*b[j]; S}

# Check equality of function results
all.equal(f1(S, b), f2(S, b))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(f2(S, b), f3(S, b))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(f1(S, b), f3(S, b))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(f1(S, b), f4(S, b))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(f2(S, b), f4(S, b))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(f3(S, b), f4(S, b))
# [1] TRUE
```

Benchmark:

```
rbenchmark::benchmark(f1(S, b), f2(S, b), f3(S, b), f4(S, b), replications=1) # 1 rep as f1() is slow
#       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1 f1(S, b)            1  12.182    12182     7.972    4.932          0         0
# 2 f2(S, b)            1   0.003        3     0.003    0.000          0         0
# 3 f3(S, b)            1   0.002        2     0.002    0.000          0         0
# 4 f4(S, b)            1   0.001        1     0.001    0.000          0         0

# longer benchmark for the other functions, drop f1()
#      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1 f2(S, b)          100   0.363    2.556     0.305    0.042          0         0
# 2 f3(S, b)          100   0.279    1.965     0.255    0.024          0         0
# 3 f4(S, b)          100   0.142    1.000     0.142    0.000          0         0
```

As you just want the `sum` it is enough to do

```
dp = diff(S@p); j = rep(seq_along(dp),dp); sum(S@x * b[S@i+1]*b[j])
```

---

Data:

```
n = 1e4 # I dont have enough memeory on my laptop for 20k
set.seed(1)
b = rnorm(n)
S = matrix(rnorm(n*n), n, n)
bw = 3
pick = (row(S)<(col(S) - bw)) | (row(S)>(col(S)+bw))
S[pick] = 0
S.r <- sample(1:n,40,replace = T)
S.c <- sample(1:n,40,replace = T)
for (i in 1:length(S.r)) {
  S[S.r[i],S.c[i]] <-0
}
S <- as(S,"sparseMatrix")
```